# Need to know how to add more values when using IF conditon

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I need to use a IF logic or any other formula.

I can do for 2 receipts. but i cannot do more than 2.

Example;
(1)Trackig#-3783588185,Receipt#-115011,Amount-$861. (2)Trackig#3604549060,Receipt#115011,Amount-$1197.

So,I use `=IF(A2(receipt#115011)=A1(receipt#115011),B2(Amount$1197)+B1(Amount$861),0)`. So my question is if it's more than 2 receipts how can i use the formula?

Comment: either nest if or use case

Comment: See the CASE construct

Comment: Is this a MySQL question? Because the `=IF(A2` part looks like Excel to me.

Comment: It's an Excell question...

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested ifs

```
=IF(A2=A1;"A2 is the same as A1";if(B2=B1;"B2 is the same as B1";if(C2=C1;"C2 is the same as C1";"Nothing is the same")))
```

You should take note that as soon as any of the above conditions evaluates as true than the true part of that statement is displayed, e.g. if both `B2=B1` and  `A2=A1` then you would only get the result "A2 is the same as A1" and might never realize that B2 is also the same as B1

Answer (score 0):

if you are after the total for a specific receipt, then `SUMIF` should work for you.

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"receipt#115011",B:B)
```

will return the sum of values in B that have a corresponding ticket in A